# How to detect when a MenuStrip gets one of its items expanded to its subitems?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, menuitem, menustrip

I have this `MenuStrip` left-docked in a Form, with `LayoutStyle = VerticalStackWithOverflow`, and I wrote these two event handlers to make its items show their text only when user moves mouse over the MenuStrip:

```
Private Sub MenuStripMainMenu_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MenuStripMainMenu.MouseEnter
    For Each c In MenuStripMainMenu.Items.OfType(Of ToolStripItem)
        c.DisplayStyle = ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.ImageAndText
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub MenuStripMainMenu_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MenuStripMainMenu.MouseLeave, MenuStripMainMenu.LostFocus
    For Each c In MenuStripMainMenu.Items.OfType(Of ToolStripItem)
        c.DisplayStyle = ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Image
    Next
End Sub
```

Although this is working ok, some of the MenuItems have their own MenuItems (as a tree of choices) and when user moves mouse from the root MenuStrip to the options, the MenuStrip shrinks back to its "icon-only" mode, so the expanded menu looks clumsy.

Is there any way to detect when a MenuStrip gets one of its items expanded to its subitems, so I can hang the proper adjustment routines?

Thank you very much!

**EDIT**

This is [DonBoitnott's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44830533/3718031) ported to VB.NET, I only added a follow-up in `MenuDeactivate` handler, to shrink the strip back to only images right after menu is deactivated:

```
Private MenuStripMainMenu_activated As Boolean = False

Private Sub MenuStripMainMenu_MenuActivate(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MenuStripMainMenu.MenuActivate
    MenuStripMainMenu_activated = True
End Sub

Private Sub MenuStripMainMenu_MenuDeactivate(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MenuStripMainMenu.MenuDeactivate
    MenuStripMainMenu_activated = False
    MenuStripMainMenu_MouseLeave(sender, e)
End Sub

Private Sub MenuStripMainMenu_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MenuStripMainMenu.MouseEnter
    For Each c In MenuStripMainMenu.Items.OfType(Of ToolStripItem)
        c.DisplayStyle = ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.ImageAndText
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub MenuStripMainMenu_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MenuStripMainMenu.MouseLeave
    If Not MenuStripMainMenu_activated Then
        For Each c In MenuStripMainMenu.Items.OfType(Of ToolStripItem)
            c.DisplayStyle = ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Image
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A combination of the events you currently have, and adding `MenuActivate` and `MenuDeactivate` can be made to behave:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Boolean _activated = false;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void menuStrip1_MouseEnter(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var c in menuStrip1.Items.OfType<ToolStripItem>())
                c.DisplayStyle = ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.ImageAndText;
        }

        private void menuStrip1_MouseLeave(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!_activated)
            {
                foreach (var c in menuStrip1.Items.OfType<ToolStripItem>())
                    c.DisplayStyle = ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Image;
            }
        }

        private void menuStrip1_MenuActivate(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _activated = true;
        }

        private void menuStrip1_MenuDeactivate(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _activated = false;
            foreach (var c in menuStrip1.Items.OfType<ToolStripItem>())
                c.DisplayStyle = ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Image;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perfect! I just added a follow-up in `MenuDeactivate` handler, to shrink the strip back to only images right after menu is deactivated. Edited my post to add the VB.NET version. Thank you so much!